# How to populate input fields with post data when validation fails codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I m coding a Tab based form using bootstrap and codeigniter.I have so many input fields and files that need to be uploaded.

And , also i have server side validation that when validation fails i show error messages but , the user is again required to fill all that long data again and i dont  want that to happen.

So, how can i repopulate the data again after a post and validation occur.

Thankyou so much , this a pain in da ass.

Comment: from CI docs [Re-populating the form](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can follow the link mentioned in the comments above and can set values using `set_value();` e.g. -

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />
```

However I had noticed that it would set values for the fields which were being validated only so I had copied and customised the set_value to my own helper function e.g.

```
function set_value_myappname($field = '', $default = '', $fieldtype='text') {

    if($fieldtype == 'text') {
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$field]))
        {
            return $default;
        }
        return form_prep($_POST[$field], $field);
    }   
}
```

please note I did that with an older version of CI. The current 3.0 might have already something else in place for this sort of behaviour.

Hope that helps.